# Modulus of the complex derivative in terms of partial derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

In Ahlfors Complex Analysis, the author writes the equation

$$|f'(z)|^2=\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)^2$$

I am wondering why this is ture. I know that  $f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ so if we were to take the modulus of $f'(z)$, wouldn't we instead get
$$|f'(z)|=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2$$

Since $|x+yi|=x^2+y^2$

Comment: "*Since $|x+yi|=x^2+y^2$*" $\;-\;$ No, that should be $|x+yi|^\color{red}{2}=x^2+y^2.\,$

Comment: @dxiv Ah of course that was a really basic mistake thanks!